# Grant permission to existing object identities with Spring Security ACL

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I'm using the Spring Security ACL implementation and am wondering what's the best way of granting a new permission to a role/user (security identity - SID) for existing object identities.

For example, let's say I have the following (I'm mostly omitting the primary keys and some other columns and simply reference by string values for readability):

- ACL_SID: `ROLE_TEST`
- ACL_CLASS: `test_class`
- ACL_OBJECT_IDENTITY:

  - id: `1`
  - object_id_class: `test_class`
  - object_id_identity: `someObjectInstanceId`
- ACL_ENTRY:

  - acl_object_identity: `1`
  - sid: `ROLE_TEST`
  - mask: `CREATE` (this would be an integer in the db)

Now, I want to grant the permission `WRITE` to the role `ROLE_TEST` for all future and existing objects of class `test_class`. For objects created in the future I will simply check the role for its permissions and grant them. But what about the existing objects?

Does Spring provide anything to easily do this or do I have to write my own custom code to do the following (which wouldn't be so bad but if Spring already provides this, I would rather not do it myself):

1. Retrieve all ACL entries with the SID of the role/user I want to grant the new permission to and that reference an object identity which has the appropriate `object_id_class`.
2. For each result, create a new ACL entry that is identical to the result except for the mask, which would reflect the new permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any build-in Spring support for this, I ended up with the following custom code. Not the most efficient but it does what I need it to do.

If anyone knows of a better solution or has suggestions for improving the below code, please let me know.

Custom JDBC ACL Service to retrieve all existing object identities by type (acl_class):

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.acls.domain.GrantedAuthoritySid;
import org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl;
import org.springframework.security.acls.domain.PrincipalSid;
import org.springframework.security.acls.model.ObjectIdentity;
import org.springframework.security.acls.model.Sid;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomJdbcAclService {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private final static String SELECT_EXISTING_BY_CLASS_AND_SID =
            "SELECT DISTINCT " +
            "acl_object_identity.object_id_identity " +
            "FROM acl_object_identity " +
            "LEFT JOIN acl_entry on acl_entry.acl_object_identity = acl_object_identity.id " +
            "LEFT JOIN acl_class on acl_class.id = acl_object_identity.object_id_class " +
            "LEFT JOIN acl_sid on acl_entry.sid = acl_sid.id " +
            "WHERE acl_class.class = ? && acl_sid.sid = ? && acl_entry.granting = 1";

    public CustomJdbcAclService(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public List<ObjectIdentity> getExistingObjectIdentities(String type, Sid sid) {
        String sidName = getSidName(sid);

        List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SELECT_EXISTING_BY_CLASS_AND_SID, type, sidName);
        List<ObjectIdentity> oids = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map<String, Object> result : results) {
            oids.add(new ObjectIdentityImpl(type, (Serializable) result.get("object_id_identity")));
        }

        return oids;
    }

    private String getSidName(Sid sid) {
        String sidName;

        if (sid instanceof PrincipalSid) {
            sidName = ((PrincipalSid) sid).getPrincipal();
        } else if (sid instanceof GrantedAuthoritySid) {
            sidName = ((GrantedAuthoritySid) sid).getGrantedAuthority();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported implementation of Sid");
        }
        return sidName;
    }

}
```

I call the above from another ACL service:

```
public class MyAclService {

public void grantPermissionsToExisting(String type, Sid securityIdentity, Permission... permissions) {
        List<ObjectIdentity> existingOids = customJdbcAclService.getExistingObjectIdentities(type, securityIdentity);
        for (ObjectIdentity oid : existingOids) {
            // grantPermissions() gets the ACL of the object identity and inserts the new ACEs
            grantPermissions(oid, securityIdentity, permissions);
        }
    }

}
```